# When using Google Billing in my app, do all of the necessary methods have to be used in the class that contains the paid content?

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing, billing

I'm following the Google In-App Purchases tutorial but it is *very* vague in most of their instructions. I have a class (let's say Sound.java) that contains sound files that can be played only after the user purchases them, considering how many lines of code are required by Google to connect to the billing services, do they all need to be in the one class, Sound.java or can I preload some of the methods in the startup class?